# The diff function for vectors

Tags: r, diff, cumsum

I am trying out R studio myself and have a question.
I have a vector

```
vec <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
```

I want to make a function to do the following: if the distance between two subsequences of 1's less then 5, then it is going to show 0. But if it is more than 5 it will show 1.

So, if looking at

```
vec <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
```

the output is going to be:

```
0 0 1
```

I understand how I can find a position of 1:

```
function_start_of_seq <- function(x) {

  one_pos<-which(rle(x)$values==1 %in% TRUE)
```

And I know that I need to use `diff` function and `cumsum`, but I don't know how...

Comment: Can you show your wanted output? What should the result be when the subsequence of 1s is not less than 5?

Comment: it will be enough if it will just show 1

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your questions is _unclear_. I realize it might make perfect sense to you but if you want assistance, you should provide a clearer explanation of what you're trying to accomplish with the full expected output for this small example. That's not asking alot for the free time of contributors.

Comment: I think what @AndersEllernBilgrau means is to edit your question to include the exact output you expect to see from the example input you posted. As hrbrmstr points out, that's the least we can expect you to do if you expect others to help you for free.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps an approach regarding rather the `0`s than the `1`s is more appropriate. In the next line you can check the lengths of the `rle()` output which distance (i.e. number of `0`s between the `1`s) exceeds the 5. Just convert it into `0-1` with `as.numeric()`at the end.

```
fun1 <- function(x) {
  null_pos <- which(rle(x)$values == 0)
  tf <- rle(x)$lengths[null_pos] > 5
  return(as.numeric(tf))
}

> fun1(vec)
[1] 0 0 1
```

Does that make sense?

In case you want a one-liner, just do

```
> as.numeric(rle(vec)$lengths[which(rle(vec)$values == 0)] > 5)
[1] 0 0 1
```

The part `which(rle(vec)$values == 0)` selects the positions with distance between `1`s sequences (i.e. the output of `rle()` regarding the `0`s) is greater than `5`.

`as.numeric()` then "translates" the output into the `0-1` - form you desire.

Comment: Even glasses never help my nigh-incessant typos in my own answers :-)

Comment: @hrbrmstr haha xD

Comment: Thank you so much! As ill get more used to R your answer will help me loads!

Answer (score 1):

An uncool, non-obfuscated, only-calling-`rle`-once, no-use-of-`which` answer:

```
vec <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)

r <- rle(vec)
r
## Run Length Encoding
##   lengths: int [1:7] 1 2 2 4 1 6 1
##   values : num [1:7] 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

So it seems the distance between the `1` sequences is what you're after. We'll assume you know you always have `0`'s and `1`'s.

`r$values == 0` will return a vector with `TRUE` or `FALSE` for the result of each positional evalution. We can use that directly in `r$lengths`.

```
rl <- r$lengths[r$values == 0]
rl
## [1] 2 4 6
```

Since it's just `0` and `1`, we don't need a `double`. `integer`s will do *just fine*:

```
as.integer(rl > 5)
## [1] 0 0 1
```

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I want! Simple and not crowded! Thank you so much!